# I came across another post showing this is how they recommend to organize lists, although I cannot figure out how to read from it

Tags: flutter, dart

I have tried things such as sportSelection['activity'] to return 'Walking' although that doesn't work, do I have to run a loop that reads them all individually? I do plan to eventually add items to this list, is there another better way you would recommend?

```
var sportSelection = {
  {
    'activity': 'Walking',
    'icon': 'assets/images/walker.png',
  },
  {
    'activity': 'Running',
    'icon': 'assets/images/runner.png',
  },
  {
    'activity': 'Weight',
    'icon': 'assets/images/weight.png',
  }
};
```

My end goal would be to plug in the activity 'Walking' and for it to return the icon..

Comment: Don't use maps.  Make real objects.

Comment: There are no `List`s in this code.  You have a `Set` of `Map`s, and you therefore will not be able to have O(1) lookups.

Comment: For this particular case, you'd be better served by having a `Map<String, String>` that maps activity strings to asset paths.  Even better would be to replace the activity strings with an `enum`.

Answer (score 0):

```
  if(sportSelection.where((e) => e["activity"] == "Walking").isNotEmpty) {
      sportSelection.firstWhere((e) => e["activity"] == "Walking")["icon"]; // returns the icon
  }
```